# Sending Email with Attachment ..VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to send email with attachment:

my code:

```
Sub SendEmailUsingGmail()
Dim Text As String
Dim Text2 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim NewMail As CDO.Message

Set NewMail = New CDO.Message

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

'Make SMTP authentication Enabled=true (1)

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

'Set the SMTP server and port Details
'To get these details you can get on Settings Page of your Gmail Account

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

'Set your credentials of your Gmail Account

 NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "shank@gmail.com"

 NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "********"

 'Update the configuration fields
NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

'Set All Email Properties

With NewMail
  .Subject = "Test Mail"
  .From = "shank@gmail.com"
  For i = 1 To 2
      Text = Cells(i, 1).Value
      Text2 = Cells(i, 2).Value
      .To = Text
      .BCC = ""
      .TextBody = ""
      .AddAttachment Text2
      Text2 = Null
      .Send
  Next i

End With

End Sub
```

It reads the email address from the first column and in the second column I have shared the address for attachments.
When it emails the last user it attaches all the attachment from the top row.
e.g:

```
spra@xyz.com    C:\Users\sprasad\Desktop\Test.docx          
sha@gwu     C:\Users\sprasad\Desktop\Test2.docx
```

**So for sha@gwu it sends out both the doc Test and Test2.**

**I just want to attach the test2 doc for sha@gwu.**
whats wrong with my code??

Comment: Your `End With` and `Next i` are the wrong way around

Comment: @Macro...could you plz explain... I am new to VBA and this my third code....

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to explain - swap `End With` and `Next i`... as it stands that code shouldn't even compile so not sure how you're running it.

Comment: You need to show more of your code in order for us to explain

Comment: For i = 1 To 2
With NewMail
  .Subject = "Test Mail"
  .From = "shank@gmail.com"
   
   Text = Cells(i, 1).Value
   Text2 = Cells(i, 2).Value
   
  .To = Text
  .BCC = ""
  .TextBody = ""
  .AddAttachment Text2
  .Send
    Text2 = ""
End With

Next i

Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line...

```
With NewMail
  .Subject = "Test Mail"
  .From = "shank@gmail.com"
  For i = 1 To 2

  Text = Cells(i, 1).Value
  Text2 = Cells(i, 2).Value
  .To = Text
  .BCC = ""
  .TextBody = ""
  .Attachments.DeleteAll       ' <--------
  .AddAttachment Text2
  Text2 = Null
  .Send
  Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this

```
For i = 1 To 2

Set NewMail = New CDO.Message

'// Rest of code here...

With NewMail
  .Subject = "Test Mail"
  .From = "shank@gmail.com"

  Text = Cells(i, 1).Value
  Text2 = Cells(i, 2).Value
  .To = Text
  .BCC = ""
  .TextBody = ""
  .AddAttachment Text2
  Text2 = Null
  .Send

End With

Next
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped by clicking the tick to the left