# How do i attach multiple sheets as one PDF to a mail using a VBA version of the built-in PDF+Attach to mail button

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

### The built in PDF-Attach button

In Excel 2013 and up, it is possible to add the *E-mail as PDF |Atachment* button to a custom ribbon. This button will publish the whole workbook, save the pdf in temp folder and attach it to a new e-mail in the default e-mail client with the workbook-name (.xlsm) as subject and no recipients.

[image: Built-in Print as PDF button]

When recording the button-click as a macro, the recorded code will not run in the same way when executed from the VBA Editor as the attachment (when run from VBAE) is going to be the *.xlsm* file because of *xlDialogSendMail*, probably due to a recording-error in Excel. (I do not know if this has been reported to the Office Dev-Team)

**Output from recording: (Does not reproduce the button action)**

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Daghan\AppData\Local\Temp\Book4.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        False
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show

End Sub
```

### My Problem

1. I want to attach two sheets as a single PDF to a mail (not the *entire* workbook)
2. I am not using Outlook (IBM Notes in fact)
3. I am able to export and save the two sheets as one pdf using *ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(...* and the conventional *ExportAsFixedFormat* methodology , but have not figured out how to attach the published pdf using VBA.

### My Questions

Do you know what *line of code* is actually executed when this built-in button in pressed?

How do i attach two sheets as a single PDF to a non-outlook mail-application?

> I would rather not take use of the Notes VBA object library as i have been
>   down that rabbit hole one too many times.

Comment: OP - I honestly doubt using `xlDialogSendMail` for this is possible, especially if you are only exporting two sheets, but maybe someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: @bigBen- yes I see that thanks for the input, the title and the facts are misleading

Comment: Maybe add lotus-notes tag as well. I don't think SO has ibm-notes as a tag yet

Comment: That's the same thing where i come from. Added

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Notes objects, then just export the PDF as you are doing it now, then use CDO.Message to send it.

See [this previous question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213884/sending-email-with-attachment-vba-code). Note that in that case, they are doing int in a loop, which you don't need, and they are using a gmail to send it - but any SMTP server that you can authenticate to should be fine, including the Lotus Domino server (which is now actually HCL, not IBM). You'll need to talk to your organization's Domino team for information about how to connect and authenticate as an SMTP sender.